# Not able to delete the blank or empty space from a command text output file on UNIX

Tags: shell, awk, aix

The command '`(sleep 4 ; echo q) | topas -P |tee /tmp/top`' on AIX  produces this output in a command text file and I am not able to remove the blank spaces from it. I have tried, sed/perl and awk commands to print only the lines containing characters however nothing has helped. Do I need to convert this file to a ASCII text format to use sed/per/grep or awk to remove the empty lines?.

```
$ file /tmp/top
/tmp/top: commands text

$ head -n33 /tmp/top






                                    DATA  TEXT  PAGE                  PGFAULTS
USER          PID     PPID PRI  NI   RES   RES SPACE    TIME  CPU%   I/O   OTH COMMAND
root      9044256 20447712  60  20 2.43M  304K 2.43M    0:00   2.1     0   253 topas
root     14942646  8913178  60  20 72.0M 37.8M 72.0M    0:42   0.2     0     1 TaniumCl
root     20447712 21889434  60  20  148K  312K  508K    0:00   0.2     0     0 ksh
root     21955056 20447712  60  20  216K 36.0K  216K    0:00   0.1     0     3 sed
root     24838602 20447712  60  20  120K 8.00K  120K    0:00   0.1     0     1 tee
root      9830690 10355194  60  20  120K 4.00K  120K    0:00   0.1     0     0 sleep
root     12255642 13893896  60  41 57.5M 39.8M 57.5M   33:42   0.1     0     0 mmfsd
root     10355194 20447712  60  20  148K  312K  508K    0:00   0.1     0     0 ksh
root      9109790  4063622  39  20 12.9M 3.68M 12.9M    5:19   0.1     0     0 rmcd
root     13697394  4063622  60  20 8.27M 55.9M 8.27M   17:18   0.1     0     0 backup_a
root     20906328        1  60  20 1.81M     0 1.81M    3:15   0.0     0     0 nfsd
root      4260244        1  60  20  620K 88.0K  620K   41:23   0.0     0     0 getty
root      1573172        0  37  41  960K     0  960K   15:17   0.0     0     0 gil
nagios    9240876  4063622  60  20 23.7M  736K 23.7M    9:43   0.0     0     0 ncpa_pas
root      4391332        1  60  20 12.5M  252K 12.5M    4:43   0.0     0     0 secldapc
a_RTHOMA  8323456 12059082  60  20  636K 3.06M 1016K    0:00   0.0     0     0 sshd
root      8388902  4063622  60  20 1.76M 1.05M 1.76M    7:03   0.0     0     0 clcomd
root      3539312        1  60  20  448K     0  448K    5:07   0.0     0     0 lock_rcv
root      3670388        1  60  20  448K     0  448K    4:18   0.0     0     0 sec_rcv
root      5767652  4063622  48   8  392K  324K  392K    2:49   0.0     0     0 xntpd
root      6816242        1  60  20 1.19M     0 1.19M    1:05   0.0     0     0 rpc.lock
root       459026        0  16  41  640K     0  640K    2:19   0.0     0     0 reaffin
root     23921008        1  60  20 1.00M     0 1.00M    4:36   0.0     0     0 n4cb
lpar2rrd 23200112 25625020  64  22  868K  120K  868K    0:00   0.0     0     0 vmstat
root      7143896        1  40  41  448K     0  448K    0:48   0.0     0     0 nfsWatch
root      6160840        1  60  20  448K     0  448K    0:09   0.0     0     0 j2gt
```

Comment: Have you tried piping the output through `od -c` to see if those blank lines are fully blank? Another option may be to just use `tail -n +7` to skip the first seven lines (if the number of blanks is consistent). What `sed` or `awk` have you already tried?

Comment: od -c would give me something like this:$ od -c /tmp/top
0000000  033   [   ?   1   h 033   = 033   [   3   9   ;   4   9   m 033
0000020    [   4   0   m 033   [   ?   1   0   4   9   h 033   (   B 033
0000040    [   m 033   [   H 033   [   2   J 033   [   3   3   m   T   o
0000060    p   a   s       M   o   n   i   t   o   r       f   o   r
0000100    h   o   s   t   :                 033   [   3   7   m   t   e
0000120    s   t   s   a   c   2   p 033   [   3   3   m               I
0000140    n   t   e   r   v   a   l   :     033   [   3   7   m   
tail -n +7 looks to be better

Comment: @ChrisJ, tail -n +7 does seem to work, I will test and confirm

Comment: @ronythomas, or `awk '/^[a-zA-Z]+/'  file` one?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your output file has some ASCII characters so it's better to print only those lines which starting from letters do like:

```
awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/' Input_file
```